# Instances interacting cause circular import error

Tags: python

I have instances of a class that depend on each other and are defined in separate scripts.

my_class.py

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
```

scriptA.py

```
import scriptB

from my_class import MyClass

foo = MyClass()
foo.value = scriptB.bar.value + 1
```

scriptB.py

```
import scriptA

from my_class import MyClass

bar = MyClass()
bar.value = 2

baz = MyClass()
baz.value = scriptA.foo.value + 1
```

scriptC.py

```
import scriptA
import scriptB

print(scriptA.foo.value + scriptB.bar.value + scriptB.baz.value)
```

I'm sourcing scriptC. I would expect for Python to calculate:

```
scriptA.foo = 3
scriptB.bar = 2
scriptB.baz = 4
```

Reality:

```
[...]
baz.value = scriptA.foo.value + 1
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'scriptA' has no attribute 'foo' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

**I do understand why it happens.** The question is what is the structure that Python expects?

Comment: Well, yeah, A imports B which import A which imports B… Don't create circular relationships, period.

Comment: Yes, I understand the cause of the error. But how should the code be structured in Python?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of circular imports. You see you are importing scriptB into scriptA but in scriptB it requires scriptA as a module to run. Try not importing scriptA and taking the required values of scriptA as a function parameter and run it as per your usage in the script.

scriptB

```py
def foo(var):
    # lets say you wanna print var
    print(var)
```

scriptA

```py
import scriptB
scriptB.foo()
```

Let me explain.
I just meant for example, you want an variable from scriptA which is required in scriptB. So, instead of importing scriptA you make an function `def foo(var)`. Now you wanna do stuff with that var so you do stuff with the var in the foo function or you can just store the value in another empty existing variable in scriptB. Now you import this foo function in scriptA. There you pass the variable you were importing earlier in this function. It will do the same thing. Instead you have to just call the function.

You do this instead of this

Having a variable called var in scriptA and trying to import it in scriptB and print. This will cause circular import as you are importing scriptA in scriptB and scriptB in scriptA.

So, for structuring

Always make a function with a parameter which you will suppose as the imported variable from the first script and do stuff in these type of problems. Like you need a's stuff in b and your import a in b and b in a. This wouldn't work. You make a function and have a parameter there which acts as the variable your importing. Then you call that function in the first script and it should work good if you did things correctly inside of that functions.

Comment: What does "taking the required values of scriptA as a function parameter and run it as per your usage in the script" mean?

Could you give an example of the code?

Comment: Sure. I just meant for example, you want an variable from scriptA which is required in scriptB. So, instead of importing scriptA you make an function ```def foo(var)```. Now you wanna do stuff with that var so you do stuff with the var in the foo function. Now you import this foo function in scriptA. There you pass the variable you were importing earlier in this function. It will do the same thing. Instead you have to just call the function.